# Implement Caliburn bootstrapper - from where to call

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I try to implement `Caliburn.Micro` and bootstrap in my `Xamarin Forms` application. I am not sure where should i call my `Bootstraper` class to correctly run application. I also have problems to overide `OnStartup` method inside my Bootstrapper class because it says it cannot find: `StartupEventArgs` and inside it's important call to: `DisplayRootViewFor<ShellView>();` therefore i commented so far that part of code.

**App :**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
}
```

**App.xaml** (where i put Bootstrapper key)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:xamarinFormsDiEaWin="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDiEaWin;assembly=XamarinFormsDiEaWin"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsDiEaWin.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <xamarinFormsDiEaWin:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Bootstrapper**

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public Bootstrapper() => Initialize();

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container.Instance(_container);
        _container
            .Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>()
            .Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

        GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass)
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(viewModelType => _container.RegisterPerRequest(
                viewModelType, viewModelType.ToString(), viewModelType));
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    //protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    DisplayRootViewFor<ShellView>();
    //}
}
```

**ShellViewModel:**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<LogOnEventModel>
{
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    private SalesViewModel _salesVM;
    private SimpleContainer _container;

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator events, SalesViewModel salesVm,
        SimpleContainer container)
    {
        _events = events;
        _salesVM = salesVm;
        _container = container;

        _events.Subscribe(this);
        ActivateItem(_container.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>());
    }

    public void Handle(LogOnEventModel message)
    {
        ActivateItem(_salesVM);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should state I'm using version 4.*. Everything will reference that version.

Your Bootstrapper mirrors my own, So it should work correctly.

The few things that are different are:

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {            
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }
```

^ this is to avoid async void.

```
private SimpleContainer Container;
```

^ I Init the container from the Configure override Like so:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    Container = new SimpleContainer();

    //FrameWork
    Container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
    Container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

    ...Rest of Your Models & Services.
}
```

The override for StartupEvent comes from namespace System.Windows Which you have labeled correctly, I would check the object browser make sure it exists there in your project.

Inside the App.xaml.cs file Should Only have the following:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

_container.Instance(_container);
```

^ Not sure why your doing this, Your calling your self.

your App.xaml is where you call the bootstrapper from.

```
private IEventAggregator _events;    
private SimpleContainer _container;
```

^These should be private readonly.

```
 ActivateItem(_container.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>());
```

This should be Injected, If you can't for some reason, Then use IoC. You shouldn't call the container directly.